# Cannot convert [...ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource] to required type [...ResourceBundleMessageSource]

Tags: java, spring

So, I try to made my project with internalization. I make

- Messages
- Messages_en
- Messages_fr

If I put them into my /resources/ everything works fine with ResourceBundleMessageSource in my context. But I want to change folder, for example to C:\Apache\servicemix\etc\conf\messages.

And when I made smth like this

Servicemix writes

```
ResourceBundle [file:C:/Apache/servicemix/etc/conf/messages/Messages] not found for MessageSource: Can't find bundle for base name file:C:/Apache/servicemix/etc/confi/messages/Messages, locale en
```

In debug mode of Servicemix I`ve tried to get correct Message from my properties and it works when I do something like

```
    ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource messageSource=new ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource();
    messageSource.setBasename("file:C:/Apache/servicemix/etc/configurator/messages/Messages");
    messageSource.getMessage("next",null,new Locale("en"));
```

I get that I need. I want to use that in my context. But
    
        
    
lead to an error:

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot convert value of type [org.springframework.context.support.ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource] to required type [org.springframework.context.support.ResourceBundleMessageSource] for property 'messageSource': no matching editors or conversion strategy found
at org.springframework.beans.TypeConverterDelegate.convertIfNecessary(TypeConverterDelegate.java:267)
at org.springframework.beans.BeanWrapperImpl.convertIfNecessary(BeanWrapperImpl.java:449)
... 140 more
```

Why it doesn`t work?
I use clear Spring, not SpringBoot

Comment: You are programming against `ResourceBundleMessageSource` as a type (of field somewhere) instead of `MessageSource` (the interface which you should use instead of the concrete type).

Comment: @M.Deinum , thank you. You was right. I had 1 ResourceBundleMessageSource  for MessageSource in 1 of my contexts. How to choose your comment as Answer? ;-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error message you get is due to the fact that somewhere in your code base you are using the `ResourceBundleMessageSource` as a type. Probably in a class which has a field of that type.

Instead of using the concrete type of `ResourceBundleMessageSource` you should be using the common interface `MessageSource` instead. This way it doesn't matter which implementation you choose to use.

Comment: Thank you for your help)